# Cannot access private member of the same class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, g++, smart-pointers

I am implementing a smart pointer class as an excerise. Consider the following:

```
class Base1 {
    protected:
        Base1() : derived_destructor_called(false) {
            printf("Base1::Base1()\n");
        }
    private:
        Base1(const Base1 &); // Disallow.
        Base1 &operator=(const Base1 &); // Disallow.
    protected:
        ~Base1() {
            printf("Base1::~Base1()\n");
            assert(derived_destructor_called);
        }
    protected:
        bool derived_destructor_called;
};

class Derived : public Base1 {
        friend void basic_tests_1();
    private:
        Derived() {printf("Derived::Derived()\n");}
        Derived(const Derived &); // Disallow.
        Derived &operator=(const Derived &); // Disallow.
    public:
        ~Derived() {
            printf("Derived::~Derived()\n");
            derived_destructor_called = true;
        }
        int value;
};
```

And the following test code:

```
            Sptr<Derived> sp(new Derived);
            // // Test template copy constructor.
            Sptr<Base1> sp3(sp);
```

Produces the following error:

```
Sptr.cpp: In instantiation of ‘my::Sptr<T>::Sptr(const my::Sptr<U>&) [with U = Derived; T = Base1]’:
Sptr.cpp:272:35:   required from here
Sptr.cpp:41:6: error: ‘Derived* my::Sptr<Derived>::obj’ is private
Sptr.cpp:117:86: error: within this context
Sptr.cpp:42:13: error: ‘my::RC* my::Sptr<Derived>::ref’ is private
Sptr.cpp:117:86: error: within this context
Sptr.cpp:43:31: error: ‘std::function<void()> my::Sptr<Derived>::destroyData’ is private
Sptr.cpp:117:86: error: within this context
```

How is this possible? I am referring to the same class variables inside the same class.!

Below is the template class prototype with its constructor declarations:

```
template <class T>
class Sptr {
private:
    //some kind of pointer
        //one to current obj
    T* obj;
    RC* ref;
    std::function<void()> destroyData;
public:
    Sptr();
    ~Sptr();

    template <typename U> 
    Sptr(U *);

    Sptr(const Sptr &);

    template <typename U> 
    Sptr(const Sptr<U> &);

    template <typename U> 
    Sptr<T> &operator=(const Sptr<U> &);

    Sptr<T> &operator=(const Sptr<T> &);

    void reset();

    T* operator->() const
    {return obj;};

    T& operator*() const
    {return *obj;};

    T* get() const
    {return &obj;};

    //operator unspecified_bool_type() const;

    //overload *,->,=,copy-constructor

    // const-ness should be preserved.
    // Test for null using safe-bool idiom
    // Static casting, returns a smart pointer
};
```

**EDIT**

I declared a template friend as follows inside the template class:

```
template<typename U> friend class Sptr;
```

That solved the above error. But it created new errors!

Test code:

```
        Sptr<Base1> sp2;
        {
            Sptr<Derived> sp(new Derived);
            // // Test template copy constructor.
            Sptr<Base1> sp3(sp);
            sp2 = sp;
            sp2 = sp2;
        }
```

Error:

```
Sptr.cpp: In instantiation of ‘my::Sptr<T>& my::Sptr<T>::operator=(const my::Sptr<U>&) [with U = Derived; T = Base1]’:
Sptr.cpp:274:23:   required from here
Sptr.cpp:128:9: error: comparison between distinct pointer types ‘my::Sptr<Base1>*’ and ‘const my::Sptr<Derived>*’ lacks a cast
Sptr.cpp:212:9: error: ‘Base1::~Base1()’ is protected
Sptr.cpp:132:21: error: within this context
Sptr.cpp: In instantiation of ‘my::Sptr<T>& my::Sptr<T>::operator=(const my::Sptr<T>&) [with T = Base1]’:
Sptr.cpp:275:23:   required from here
Sptr.cpp:212:9: error: ‘Base1::~Base1()’ is protected
Sptr.cpp:154:21: error: within this context
```

How is this possible when I have already made it a template friend? Below the = operator overloaded

```
template <typename T> 
Sptr<T>& Sptr<T>::operator=(const Sptr<T> &t) {

    std::cout<<"= const <T>\n";
    if(this != &t) {
        if(ref->Release() == 0) {

            if(obj)
                delete obj;

            delete ref;       
        }

        obj = t.obj;
        ref = t.ref;
        destroyData = t.destroyData;
        ref->AddRef();
    }

    return *this;
}
template <typename T> 
template <typename U> 
Sptr<T>& Sptr<T>::operator=(const Sptr<U> &t) {

    std::cout<<"= const <U>\n";
    if(this != &t) {
        if(ref->Release() == 0) {

            if(obj)
                delete obj;

            delete ref;       
        }

        obj = t.obj;
        ref = t.ref;
        destroyData = t.destroyData;
        ref->AddRef();
    }

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: The new errors were not 'created' by the fix, but were likely *revealed* once the hurdle of the previous mistake was removed.

Comment: see my updated answer for the new errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class is different; your constructor is

```
my::Sptr<Base1>::Sptr(const my::Sptr<Derived>&)
```

and you're trying to access members of `my::Sptr<Derived>`.

You need to declare a template friend:

```
template<typename U> friend class Sptr;
```

Comment: what you said worked, But look at my question edit. How can I solve that? Its essentially the same problem again.

Comment: wont all the functions inside it become friends once I declare the template friend you said?

Comment: @footy yes, that's the case. If you don't want that, either provide public methods to get the pointer and refcount, or provide methods to explicitly convert a `Sptr<U>` to a `Sptr<T>` via some constructor that accepts a refcount.

Answer (score 4):

> I am referring to the same class variables inside the same class.

No, you're not. Maybe you are referring to the same members of the same class *template*, I guess something like

```
    template <typename U> 
    Sptr(const Sptr<U> & other) : obj(other.obj), ref(other.ref) {}
```

But you are *not* accessing members of the same *class*, since `Sptr<Base>` and `Sptr<Derived>` are different instantiations of the template and thus are different classes that cannot touch each other's privates.

**Update to your edit:** The error you are getting now is not related to access rights, but it's again related to `Sptr<Base>` and `Sptr<Derived>` being different classes, so pointers to them are different pointer types that cannot be compared.
The code you are showing is `operator=` for the same template instantiation (`Sptr<T>`), but the error occurs in the operator for a different template instantiation (`Sptr<U>`). I guess you have the adress comparison in there as well, which is not necessary, since a `Sptr<T>` cannot have the same address as a `Sptr<U>`.

The second error about protected `~Base` is obvious: you made `~Base` protected and nonvirtual, meanong you won't destroy `Base` objects by deletion of `Base*` pointers. The same then applies for smart pointers to `Base`, because they would use polymorphic deletion which you prohibited. Solution: Make the `~Base` public and virtual.

Comment: @Ame I know I may sound strange. But thats the test code I HAVE to pass . Whats the work around? Or is there one?

Comment: Well, the test code is ok, but parts of the `Sptr` implementation and the declaration of `~Base` as nonvirtual protected is not. Change the latter and fix the templated `operator=` and your test code will work like a charm.

Comment: @Ame can you give me a hint on how to make the `operator=` work? I am bit new to template styled programming

Comment: @footy as I said, leave the address comparison, i.e. erase the line `if (this != &t)` since that is the comparison giving the error and it can never be false.

Comment: what happens when self assignment happens? i.e `a=a;` type or `a=<cast to some lower type> a;`

Comment: ok! I got it. :) Just a small doubt.. a=a wont be a problem. But when a=<cast to lower type> a; happens?

Comment: `a=a` wouldn't be the templated `operator=`, because both are the same type. A cast to `Sptr<Derived>` from `Sptr<Base>`is not trivially possible, but if it was, the cast would give you a temporary `Sptr<Derived>` object, whose address is clearly not the same as the address of a. You would have two objects pointing to the same ref and object, which won't hurt much, although you would needlessly copy that pointers and release and add the same ref. So while you could check if the ref pointers already are the same, it is not necessary for program correctness.

Answer (score 2):

They're not the same class. It looks like it's complaining about you trying to access members of `Sptr<Derived>` from `Sptr<Base1>` - look at the type variable instantiations at the start of the error message.

Templates, when their type variables are filled in, generate entirely new classes that just happen to look very similar, so a `MyClass<string>` is not the same as a `MyClass<vector<int>>`.